# What is the property of a function f such that $f = f^n$ for $1 \lt n \lt \infty$?

Tags: functions

In other words, what is a function of which multiple applications are equivalent to one called?

A trivial example off the top of my head would be:
$f(x) = x \times 0$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Please take some time to read how to format math equations using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your question. Also, please provide a little more context, like what you need this information for and whether you want more examples or not.

Comment: You are getting wrong answers because your question is not quite clear. Please rephrase the question in your title in the question body too, explain your notation and ask precise questions (What is the name of this property, not what is a function that...)

Comment: I think that you're being a bit harsh here sir, I did take some time to make it as clear as I can given I didn't study mathematics. Also, this is my first question here, I am planing on learning to format things better when I have time. Finally, altough phrased awkwardly, I did ask "What is a function (...) called?", so I am asking for an adjective, such as "idempotent". Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Still learning to moderate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any context, this property is called "idempotence". The function $f$ is called *idempotent* because applying it many times has the same result as applying it just once. Examples of idempotent functions (or operations) are multiplying by $0$, multiplying by $1$, adding $0$, projections, etc. See [the Wikipedia article on idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

In several contexts "projections" have this property. For example
$$
p(x,y) = (x,0)
$$
projects points in the coordinate plane to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're thinking too much. It's a one word property I'm thinking about, I used to know it but I forgot. With this property, if you have an object, and you apply the function several times to the object, you're getting the same object as if you only applied it once.

Comment: I'm a programmer, and what I'm thinking about is having a button (that applies a function) that if you click a bunch of times, you end up with the same result as if you'd clicked it once.

Comment: @egglog The identity function would be an example of functions having this property.

Comment: @AndreiToroplean Idempotent?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Exactly!

Comment: Said in other words again, if you think of multiple applications of such function, you instantly converge to the end result.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Perfect, that's the word! Post it as a reply ;)